# How to archive an NSArray of custom objects to file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nskeyedarchiver

Can you show me the syntax or any sample programs to archive an NSArray of custom objects in Objective-C?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out **[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**.

For Archiving your array, you can use the following code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray] forKey:@"mySavedArray"];
```

And then for loading the custom objects in the array you can use this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *savedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"mySavedArray"];
if (savedArray != nil)
{
        NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedArray];
        if (oldArray != nil) {
                customObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        } else {
                customObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
}
```

Make sure you check that the data returned from the user defaults is not `nil`, because that may crash your app.

The other thing you will need to do is to make your custom object to comply to the `NSCoder` protocol. You could do this using the `-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` and `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save to a file (rather than using NSUserDefaults) you can use `-initWithContentsOfFile:` to load, and `-writeToFile:atomically:` to save, using NSArrays.

Example:

```
- (NSArray *)loadMyArray
{
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myArrayFile", NSHomeDirectory()]];
    return arr;
}

// returns success flag
- (BOOL)saveMyArray:(NSArray *)myArray
{
    BOOL success = [myArray writeToFile:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myArrayFile", NSHomeDirectory()]];
    return success;
}
```

There's a lot of examples on various ways to do this here: http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/167