# How to read array of custom objects from a plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have read many question how to save custom objects but I m not getting a idea. I don't know what to do next thats why I am asking a question.

**Save custom object in plist file**

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.drawingView.pathArray);
NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.drawingView.pathArray];
[arrayData writeToFile:[DOCUMENTPATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.plist"] atomically:YES];
```

**Console o/p**

```
(
    "<PenTool: 0xa031f80;>",
    "<PenTool: 0x8b2b360;>",
    "<PenTool: 0xa03aca0;>",
    "<PenTool: 0x8b38780;>"
)
```

The above code works fine. Save in plist. Now I want to get back all the objects from that plist.

**Read from plist**

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[DOCUMENTPATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.plist"]];
self.pathArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Here I am getting a data. but not a array. I have read about that but there are saying you have to **unarhive** data. But i don't have idea how to unarhive.

EDIT

I know I have to use below two method but not getting a idea.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
}
```

Is there any other way to store custom objects in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PenTool` class needs to implement `NSCoding`. This is described the [Archives and Serialisations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493156/how-to-archive-an-nsarray-of-custom-objects-to-file-in-objective-c) has a couple of useful examples.

These code snippets are from the Archives and Serialisations Programming Guide, the keys are strings.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
   [coder encodeObject:self.firstName forKey:ASCPersonFirstName];
   [coder encodeObject:self.lastName forKey:ASCPersonLastName];
   [coder encodeFloat:self.height forKey:ASCPersonHeight];
}


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      _firstName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:ASCPersonFirstName];
      _lastName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:ASCPersonLastName];
      _height = [coder decodeFloatForKey:ASCPersonHeight];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: yes that i have to do NSCoding.. but your question link not providing any answer for NSCoding. i dont have any idea about NSCoding. please guide me

Comment: See the Encoding and Decoding chapter in the Archives and Serialisations Programming Guide.

Comment: Hopefully the above copy & paste from programming guide explains what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically plist is a way of saving data in NSDictionary, so I guess you should leave the array alone and start using dictionary in that case

Comment: But I have custom objects with all the drawing porperty.. how can I take dictionary here

Comment: Is there any other way to store custom objects